# How to display a text file on a webpage with original formatting

Tags: php, html

So im pretty annoyed i cant get this one simple little task completed after doing PHP for the entire night.. but the server im hosting on wont allow you to href text files directly.. I mean, it will, but it will display a blank window.. So i decided i'd build a php for the href and that php can have a statement to include the file.. so far ive tried:

```
include();
require();
file_get_contents();
```

They all work, but they all ignore formatting and continuously print the text file across the screen.. How can i print the file with its original formatting? I essentially need it to worry about new lines.

Thanks guys

Comment: You really should read about the tools you use. Start with reading about how html presentation in a browser works. Then you can answer yourself _why_ you do not see the formatting you expected when you deliver the text content the way you do. Don't try around, try to understand _why_ things are happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are embedding the text in a HTML document, you can enclose a piece of text in `<pre>...</pre>` tags to preserve its formatting.

On modern browsers you can achieve the same thing by setting the CSS `white-space` property to `pre`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the MIME type of the page using the `Content-type` header:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
echo '<p><em>This</em> won\'t be treated as HTML...</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<pre>` tag to keep the formatting of the original text.